# How to get this Managed Package namespace in LWC component

Tags: managed-package, lightning-web-components

We are writing LWC component which is a part of our managed package. And there is a need to have package namespace available in javascript variable there for further manipulation etc.

Is there any way to get current package namespace in LWC component without calling server-side method? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import fields in LWC:

```
import SAMPLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SampleObject__c.SampleField__c';
```

Imported fields get namespaces automatically by salesforce:

```
SAMPLE_FIELD.fieldApiName; // NAMESPACE__SampleField__c
```

you can just get the namespace from the field, this also works for objects.